# How to return html on get method in Spring app?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have maybe very ease question, I already using Spring mvc + jsp, but now I can not understand why the controller does not return the html file. Now I use Spring Boot with the Web module.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public class Main {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger
            .getLogger(Main.class.getName());

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
        return "templates/hello.html";
    }
```

And my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>HelloWorld</title>
</head>
  <body>
  HELLO
  </body>
</html>
```

I always get error:

> Whitelabel Error Page
>   This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>   Sat Feb 17 20:22:24 EET 2018
>   There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
>   No message available

Build file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.10.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

group = 'mikhailov.diplom.ae'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf
    compile group: 'org.thymeleaf', name: 'thymeleaf', version: '3.0.9.RELEASE'

}
```

Comment: And how do you call your endpoint?

Answer (score -1):

As from your build file, you are using thymeleaf:

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf
    compile group: 'org.thymeleaf', name: 'thymeleaf', version: '3.0.9.RELEASE'

}
```

The "problem" with this approach is that you must explicitly define the thymeleaf templateResolver bean and the templateEngine.

On the other side, spring-boot comes with an out-of-the-box solution, that is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

which has everything conventionally configured. In this case, you don't need to define your templeteResolver or your templateEngine (unless you don't really need to) and you can start using your templates simply by returning the String with the correct name.

With the spring dependency, you just remove the "templates" prefix and the .html ext from the returned string, and it will work as expected:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index() {
    return "hello";
}
```

Comment: No, i don't use thymeleaf (

Comment: Is it a spring-boot app? Can you post your pom.xml?

Comment: @senape I think that he would get different error code than 404 in case of missing template (500 most likely)

Comment: @ОлегМихайлов `compile group: 'org.thymeleaf', name: 'thymeleaf', version: '3.0.9.RELEASE'` says you are using thymeleaf